# What is the __builtin_expect() prototype?

Tags: c, powerpc, misra

To get rid of a static code analysis warning (QA-C), I need to provide a function prototype for `__builtin_expect()`.

I am using the **WindRiver Diab** compiler for PowerPC.
In the compiler manual I have found the following information:

> `__builtin_expect(long exp, long c)`: ... `exp` is also the return value.

So, my prototype is as follows:

```
long __builtin_expect(long exp, long c);
```

However, it does not compile, I am getting the following error:

> **error (dcc:1701):** invalid types on prototype to intrinsic __builtin_expect - when the intrinsic is enabled, optional user prototype must match

It seems like my prototype is not correct. What is the correct prototype for `__builtin_expect`?

The error message states that the user prototype is optional. So it should be possible to define it, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to somehow define `__builtin_expect` to make your static analyzer happy, because it doesn't know what that function is.  But you need to use `#ifdef` to disable that definition when you are compiling your program normally, because your compiler will not like it if you try to define compiler builtins yourself.  The builtins come with the compiler so they are not supposed to be defined in your program.

Something like this would work:

```
#ifdef _HEY_I_AM_RUNNING_STATIC_ANALYZER
#define __builtin_expect(e,c) (e)
#endif
```

I don't know the details of how your static analyzer works, so I don't know what the right macro is to test in the `#ifdef`.  You can read the documentation of your static analyzer to find out if it defines any preprocessor symbols by default, or if you can tell it what preprocessor symbols to define when you run it.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Still would like to know how the prototype should look like.

Comment: You don't need an actual prototype, you just need a macro that makes your static analyzer ignore __builtin_expect.  Did you try following my advice from the answer above?  If it didn't work for you, why not?

Answer (score 5):

You should carefully read the documentation of [Other Builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) in GCC.

As a first approximation, you might replace `__builtin_expect` by (invocation `_builtin_expect_replacement` of) the macro below:

```
#define _builtin_expect_replacement(Exp,C) (Exp)
```

For most static analyzers that should be enough

Don't expect most GCC builtins to be definable as functions.

Comment: @sergej: I think the suggestion is to replace every occurrence of `__builtin_expect` with `__builtin_expect2`, so you can #define __builtin_expect2 to be __builtin_expect. The analyzer will see the macro definition and stay happy. Perhaps.

Comment: @linuxfan I think the analyzer will try to expand the macro before analyzing.

Comment: @sergej I think it too. Looking better, my previous comment was wrong. The #define in the answer seems to cancel out the builtin and use "Exp" as is. Put this way, it works - but perhaps it is not what you want. Probably, you could activate this macro *only* when analyzing.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, This would disable `__builtin_expect`, that's not what I want.